# hard time trying to discover whats wrong with a sp_executesql with params

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a stored procedure to drop all triggers that follow a name schema basead on the table name (after this I will create another trigger).

So, first, I tried to use a cursor to list all tables that ends with `__ATTACH`, then check if this table has a trigger with name that starts with `UPDATE_ATT_NAME__`, and if exists, drop this trigger.

My sp:

```
DECLARE @table_name NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @trigger_name NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE tables_cursor CURSOR FOR
  SELECT TABLE_NAME
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE '%ATTACH'
  FOR READ ONLY;

OPEN tables_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cursor INTO @table_name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
    /* Check if trigger exists */
    SET @trigger_name = CONCAT('UPDATE_ATT_NAME__', @table_name);
    IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@trigger_name)))
      /* drop trigger */
      BEGIN
        DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
        DECLARE @param NVARCHAR(MAX);

        SET @sql = N'DROP TRIGGER @tn';
        SET @param = N'@tn NVARCHAR(MAX)';

        EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, @param, @tn = @trigger_name;
      END

    FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cursor INTO @table_name
  END
CLOSE tables_cursor;
DEALLOCATE tables_cursor;
```

But I always receive with something like this (my sql server it's not english, so, I don't known the correct error message on english - I have translated):

`Incorrect syntax found during sp_executesql next to '@tn'`

Using a `PRINT` with `REPLACE` instead of `EXECUTE sp_executesql` (poor man debug), I don't see anything wrong.

`PRINT REPLACE(@sql, '@tn', @trigger_name)`

Got `DROP TRIGGER UPDATE_ATT_NAME__TEST_TABLE_NAME__ATTACH`

UPDATE,
I got working this using

```
SET @sql = N'DROP TRIGGER ' + @trigger_name;
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
```

But I really don't get how to use with params

Comment: You can't use object names in variables like that. You would need to concatenate the string to the executed sql instead. [The curse and blessings of dynamic SQL - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: Are you trying to delete all triggers with a prefix of 'UPDATE_ATT_NAME__' for all tables named  like '%ATTACH' ? You don't need cursors or looping for this.

Comment: @SeanLange, yes, I known, but If you read my question, after this, I will create another trigger for every table, and every trigger is basead on table name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not something really straight forward like this instead? Here we are leveraging the system objects to generate our dynamic sql.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'drop trigger ' + t. name + ';'
FROM sys.triggers t
join sys.objects o on t.parent_id = o.object_id
where o.name like '%ATTACH'
    and t.name like 'UPDATE_ATT_NAME__%'

select @SQL --uncomment the following line when satisfied the dynamic sql generated is correct
--exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: because on every loop, after drop my trigger, I will create another trigger with name basead on table name too (I don't put this on my question to keep simple) with some dynamic trigger basead on table (some tables has different triggers than others)

Comment: Still don't understand why you need loops here. If the triggers are all the same (except for the name of course) you could us the same concept.

Comment: Then you will have to code your triggers manually anyway. The loop isn't going to help. The code I posted here will drop all your existing triggers. If you need help with creating new triggers you need to provide some details for that.

Comment: I have a logic. I have 3 different triggers, and I need to create the triggers basead on table name. I have almost 350 tables (it's a geodatabase), so, no, no way I will create manually! I already create using string concatenation (see my update question).

Comment: I think you forgot to update your question....there is nothing about an insert trigger based on names. And to be fair in nearly 20 years I have created maybe 4-5 triggers and could probably reduce that today to about 2-3. 350 in a single database seems like perhaps there might be a better way of approaching your problem.

Comment: first sentence of my question: `I'm trying to create a stored procedure to drop all triggers that follow a name schema basead on the table name (after this I will create another trigger).`. If I put all my sp procedure here, with 3 different triggers and all the logic, I will have to put my table schema too, and the question will be very complex. anyway, tks for the help!

Comment: OK. Still how do you expect a loop to generate your new triggers if they are all different? You would have to include ALL of your trigger logic inside your loop. At any rate, my answer does answer your question about how to drop all the existing triggers. Apparently you have a script already to generate the 350 or so triggers you want to create.

Comment: yes, I already have a script to generate all the triggers, and yes, all the logic is inside the loop (i known this is bad)!

Comment: Without seeing the code I can't offer much help there. But if they are all different why not just create it as a script and run it?

Comment: several reasons and mainly because other developer already created almost all the trigger (it's huge). anyway, I don't agree with the way all the triggers are created, but I don't have time to create all again in a better way. again, tks for all the help

Comment: @SeanLange When dealing with triggers, it is indeed a race to the bottom :). I beat you by 1-2, I've created three in my 20 year carreer :p